# Generalization of higher derivatives of function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Tags: analysis, derivatives

The derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ at $a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a linear transformation $Df(a):\mathbb{R}^{n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Is it right to say that the second derivative of $f$ at $a$ is the derivative of $Df(a)$ at $a$? Generally, is the $k$th derivative of $f$ at $a$ the $(k-1)$th derivative of $Df(a)$ at $a$?

Comment: Since $Df(a)$ is linear, its derivative is constant and its higher derivatives are zero.  By analogy with single variable calculus, $Df(a)$ is the tangent line at $a$ and taking derivatives of the tangent line does not tell you much about the function.

Answer (score 0):

No. The derivative of a linear map $\phi : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ at any point $x \in \mathbb R^n$ is $\phi$ itself. Thus your idea would mean that all higher derivatives of $f$ at $a$ are $Df(a)$.

For a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ we must consider the derivative as a function $f' : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ to determine $f''$. It does not suffice to consider the single value $f'(a)$ to get $f''(a)$.

In the multivariable case we must similarly consider the derivative as a function $Df : \mathbb R^n \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$  = vector space of all linear maps $ \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. It is easy to see that $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ can be identified with $\mathbb R^{n \cdot m}$ and so you can move on to determine $D^2f$.

Note that in the multivariable sense $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has a derivative $Df : \mathbb R \to \mathcal L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R) \approx \mathbb R$. The isomorphism is given by $L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)  \ni \phi \mapsto \phi(1) \in \mathbb R$ (or equivalently by $\mathbb R \ni r \mapsto \phi _r \in L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$, where $\phi_r(x) = rx$). In other words, the linear map $Df(a)$ is given by $Df(a)(x) = f'(a)x$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no doubt that we should put all the partial derivatives of order $k$ together to make it the higher derivative of $f$. The question is how to organize them into a single meaningful entity, just like we put all the first order derivatives into a matrix (the Jacobian matrix, or $D(f)$) so that it can be interpreted as a linear transformation (in a coordinate-free fashion).

It's also well-known that we can put all the order 2 partial deivatives together to make the Hessian matrix $H(f)$, but the Hessian matrix is not to be understood as a linear map, rather it defines a bilinear form $h(x,y) = x^t H y$ (where $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ are column vectors).

More generally, we can define $D^n(f)(a)$ as a symmetric $n$-multiliear form on $\mathbb R^n$ (a "tensor" if I may), such that the Taylor expansion holds: $$f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i!}D^{(i)}(f)(a)(x-a, \cdots, x-a) + o(\|x-a\|^n)$$

For more details, you can read [Brain Conrad's Notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/taylor.pdf), where he details the reason why $D(D(f))$ which is the derivative of linear transformations can also be understood as a bilinear form, and so on.